# ¿Es "está tan bonito que te lo van a robar" un dicho en español?

Tags: expresiones, modismos, latinismo, significado-en-contexto

Soy latina y hablo español, pero no vivo en Latinoamérica y español no es mi idioma fuerte. 
Entonces quiero aclarar un dicho que quizás es común en otro país, pero yo no lo he escuchado.

Un señor (no conocido) vino a mi casa a hacer un trabajo. Vio a mi niño de un año y dijo que está tan bonito que me lo van a robar.

Siguió repitiendo que me lo van a robar unas 4/5 veces ¡me saco tanto de onda que son las 3 de la mañana y sigo despierta! 
Parece que el es de El Salvador.

Mil disculpas si soy ignorante y un million de gracias por una respuesta que me ponga a calma.

Answer (score 1):

Tranquila, no es que te vaya a robar al niño, es que afortunadamente para ti, tu peque es muy rico/guapo/'cute'.... Es una exageración pero no te lo van a robar, es una manera de hablar. En España se usan las exageraciones mucho. Como por ejemplo: 'Te he dicho mil veces que no seas exagerado', esta es muy común, pero no lo ha dicho mil veces, seguramente ni 100 pero está cansado de decirlo. Y en tu ejemplo igual, es una exageración.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias, Iria!  Ahora que lo leo si me pone más tranquila:) apenas nos venimos a vivir a Texas y recibo noticias que es uno de los estados más conocidos por secuestró de niño ....entonces me puso un poco paranoica! Te lo agradezco:)